# Express serving static files for link preview

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a route on my Express server which looks like that :

```js
app.get('/:summoner/icon.png', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { data } = await $LoL.getSummonerIcon(req.params.summoner);
  const url = await $server.download(data.iconUrl, 'img/profile_icons', `${data.iconId}`);
  // url is that path to the downloaded file on the server
  res.sendFile(url);
});
```

But the problem is, when I send the link to someone through IM I am supposed to have a preview of the link, which I haven't. The route serves me an actual file in the browser, not a html page or anything else.

What is the problem, does Express need to consider the file as a static file and use `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` ?

Or am I just doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't understand why you expect `sendFile` to send something other than the file you tell it to send. Where is this HTML page supposed to appear from? You haven't written any code to create it.

Comment: @Quentin I don't expect it to send anything else than a file. It was just testing and say that I tried but doesn't work.

Comment: Then I don't understand what the difference between "The route serves me an actual file in the browser" and "It works" is.

Comment: The file is served in the browser but is not displayed on IM There is supposed to be a preview of the file right under the link and this is what I need. Someone commented it was maybe a MIME or Header issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question : it turns out the problem does not come from me, and also it is not an actual problem. I was testing locally, and the preview is not generated from the client, but server side, I don't know why.

So even if I put a local address the preview will not be generated.

I used `localtunnel` to expose my local app, and with the address provided by the program, I could finally see the preview.